# Help understanding jQuery selector example

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code was taking from the [timers](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/)  jQuery plugin demo.  I don't understand what is happening in the selector in line 2.  It seems it is selecting the p element, but then what is the second argument after the comma - `demos` - there for?

**jQuery:**

```
var demos = $("div.wrapper div.demos");             
$(".uncontrolled-interval p", demos).everyTime(1000,function(i) {
                    $(this).html(i);
                });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="demos">         
        <div class="uncontrolled-interval"> 
            <p>I am transient... *sigh*</p> 
        </div>      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It specifies the context of the search. Basically a filter.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#expressioncontext

So in this example it searches the `demos` element for `.uncontrolled-interval p`. If you have this markup, it would still only select the one in `demos`.

```
<div class="wrapper">          
    <div class="uncontrolled-interval"> 
        <p>I am transient... *sigh*</p> //Will not select
    </div>     
    <div class="demos">         
        <div class="uncontrolled-interval"> 
            <p>I am transient... *sigh*</p> //Will select
        </div>      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When selecting elements with jQuery using the `jQuery` function (or its alias `$`), you can provide a context as well as a selector as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

What that says is: select every element that matches the provided CSS **selector** within the given **context**, with **context** meaning the region of the DOM that you have already selected.

Put another way, it says: use the **context** as the root of the DOM tree being searched, as opposed to the document root.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to others answer, context works like [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Internally, selector context is
>   implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to
>   $(this).find('span').

Personnaly, I prefer write `demos.find(".uncontrolled-interval p")` to `$(".uncontrolled-interval p", demos)`